# Differences between Windows Desktop APIs and C Runtime library?

Tags: c, windows

For the purpose of this question I'm only interested in desktop applications, both GUI and command line.

What are the differences between the [Universal C Runtime aka C Run-Time Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/crt-alphabetical-function-reference?view=vs-2017) and the
[Desktop APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/index)?

What's the difference in terms of availability – which API runs on more versions of Windows? Is there a size/performance cost to using both in the same application? What's the difference in robustness in handling of edge cases e.g. a unicode filename?

It seems the Desktop APIs are more powerful than the Universal C Runtime? Is the latter built on the former, making the former a strict superset in terms of functionality? Is for example [`_open`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/open-wopen?view=vs-2017) in fact implemented on top of [`CreateFileW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew)?

Comment: It depends on the needs of your application. The Desktop APIs are more "powerful" in the sense that they offer more functionality, but if you don't need it, they may also add complexity.

Comment: "Which should I prefer to use?" is asking for opinions.  Stackoverflow tries to focus more on facts than opinions.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy I've removed the preference part of the question. The remainder – specific technical questions of fact – I believe does not fall foul of the rules and thus this questions should be reopened.

Comment: Yes, `_[w]open` calls `CreateFileW`, which in turn calls `NtCreateFile`, a system call stub that switches to kernel mode and dispatches to the real `NtCreateFile`.

Comment: FYI, `NtCreateFile` calls `IoCreateFileEx`, which sets up an open packet and calls `ObOpenObjectByNameEx`. This parses the path, including object directories and symbolic links (e.g. "\??\C:" -> "\Device\HarddiskVolume2") up to an object with a parse routine. A device uses `IopParseDevice`, which checks for the actual target device (e.g. a mounted file-system)  and calls the driver for the device stack via `IofCallDriver` with an `IRP_MJ_CREATE` request. The device parses the rest of the path. For a reparse point (e.g. junction or symlink), the request returns back to `ObOpenObjectByNameEx`.

Comment: @eryksun Thank you that's very helpful, and impressively detailed!